# Why am I getting "Array to string conversion error"?

Tags: php

Currently attempting to grab a list of avatars for a user powered site I'm developing. But I'm getting "Array to string conversion" error within the PHP. The code is (in theory) supposed to find out 1. Who the user is following, and 2. Display the avatar of the followed users. Any help is appreciated.

**PHP:**

```
$user_recent = new USER();

$user_id = $_SESSION['userID'];

$stmt = $user_recent->runQuery("SELECT user2_id FROM following WHERE user1_id=:userid ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 12");
$stmt->execute(array(":userid"=>$user_id));
$recent = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$stmt = $user_recent->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE userID=:avatarid ORDER BY userID DESC LIMIT 12");
$stmt->execute(array(":avatarid"=>$recent));
$recentchannels = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$channeldata = '';

if(count($recentchannels) > 0)
 {
  foreach($recentchannels as $recentchannel)
  {

  $channeldata .= '
   <div class="avatarwrap"><a href="index.php?id='.$recentchannel["userID"].'"><img class="avatar" src="'.$recentchannel["avatar"].'"></a></div>
   ';

  }
 }
 else
 {
  $channeldata .= '<div class="avatarwrap"><a href=""><img class="avatar" src="images/avatar2.jpg"></a></div>';
 }

header('Content-type: application/json');
$channel_array = array('channeldata'=>$channeldata);
echo json_encode($channel_array);
```

Error is occuring with: $stmt->execute(array(":avatarid"=>$recent));

Comment: what line is the error on, and more specifically, what line is it in the code you posted?

Comment: The error is in line 10

Comment: $stmt->execute(array(":avatarid"=>$recent));

Comment: `$recent` is an array, not a string

Comment: thanks! so that is your issue: pdo::fetchAll gives you an array, as you would expect, but the array passed to execute should be a list of key value pairs of strings, that is, `$recent` needs to be a string, not an array. see http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php for more info

Comment: It should be $stmt->execute(array(":avatarid"=>$recent['user2_id']));

Comment: @Hackerman wouldn't it be `$recent[0]['user2_id']`

Comment: Maybe or maybe not, but that's the issue.

Comment: No maybes about it. `$recent` will be a 2-dimensional array